# how to determine if the selection is inside a textbox or not

Tags: vba, textbox, ms-word

A few textbox are created by repeating

```
Set Shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 
          Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=100, Height:=100)
```

how to determine if the current cursor (or selection) is inside one of the textbox or not? I want to move the cursor out of the textbox if it is in, and do not move the cursor if it is not in.

Comment: You can use `Selection.StoryType` to check if the selection is inside a TextFrame. `Selection.Shaperange(1)` to get the textbox. Moving the cursor outside of the textbox is tricky if it isn't an inline shape. (using the anchor is the only way I can think of right now)

Comment: Selection.StoryType does the trick. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can determine whether your selection is inside a textbox by checking the `StoryType` property of the selected range:

```
Set Shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=100, Height:=100)

If Selection.StoryType = WdStoryType.wdTextFrameStory Then

    ' select the paragraph the shape is anchored to
    Shp.Anchor.Select

    ' collapse to the beginning of the paragraph
    Selection.Collapse
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to get the code from here for getting/setting mouse position:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/152969

Then write the following

```
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseMove(ByVal intButton As Integer, ByVal intShift As Integer, ByVal sngWidth As Single, ByVal sngHeight As Single) 

    If (sngWidth < 5 Or sngWidth > TextBox1.Width - 5) Or (sngHeight < 5 Or sngHeight > TextBox1.Height - 5) Then 
        SetCursorPos x, y
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: The question is about a textbox in a Microsoft Word document, not about a Windows Forms textbox so your code sample does not apply here.